# React Native Expo Error downloading and extracting template package: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting started with react native using expo-cli version 5.4.9 on ubuntu OS.
Successfully installed expo but getting this error on initializing new app

[image: error image]

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120003/enoent-when-i-try-to-start-the-expo), its work for me. I mean promlem in expo downloader.

Answer (score 0):

i has this same problem, reinstall npm and nodejs for update new version, after this resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32319490)